# Making a specific quantile plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, data-visualization

I am very intrigued by the [following visulization (Decile term)](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/glossary-of-common-statistics-and-machine-learning-terms/#Four)

[image]

And I wonder how it would be possible to do it in R.

There is of course histograms and density plots, but they do not make such a nice visualization. Especially, I would like to know if it possible to do it with `ggplot`/`tidyverse`.

**edit** in response to the comment

`library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
someData <- data_frame(x = rnorm(1000))
ggplot(someData, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_histogram()`
 
 this produces a histogram (see http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=LQXazwMY&version=1)

But how I can get the coloful bars? How to implement the small rectangles? (The arrows are less relevant).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to define a number of breaks, and use approximate deciles that match those histogram breaks. Otherwise, two deciles will end up in one bar.

```
d <- data_frame(x = rnorm(1000))

breaks <- seq(min(d$x), max(d$x), length.out = 50)
quantiles <- quantile(d$x, seq(0, 1, 0.1))
quantiles2 <- sapply(quantiles, function(x) breaks[which.min(abs(x - breaks))])

d$bar <- as.numeric(as.character(cut(d$x, breaks, na.omit((breaks + dplyr::lag(breaks)) / 2))))
d$fill <- cut(d$x, quantiles2, na.omit((quantiles2 + dplyr::lag(quantiles2)) / 2))

ggplot(d, aes(bar, y = 1, fill = fill)) +
  geom_col(position = 'stack', col = 1, show.legend = FALSE, width = diff(breaks)[1])
```

[image]

Or with more distinct colors:

```
ggplot(d, aes(bar, y = 1, fill = fill)) +
  geom_col(position = 'stack', col = 1, show.legend = FALSE, width = diff(breaks)[1]) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = 'qual', palette = 3) # The only qual pallete with enough colors
```

[image]

Add some styling and increase the breaks to 100:

```
ggplot(d, aes(bar, y = 1, fill = fill)) +
  geom_col(position = 'stack', col = 1, show.legend = FALSE, width = diff(breaks)[1], size = 0.3) +
  scale_fill_brewer(type = 'qual', palette = 3) +
  theme_classic() +
  coord_fixed(diff(breaks)[1], expand = FALSE) + # makes square blocks
  labs(x = 'x', y = 'count')
```

[image]

And here is a function to make that last one:

```
decile_histogram <- function(data, var, n_breaks = 100) {
  breaks <- seq(min(data[[var]]), max(data[[var]]), length.out = n_breaks)
  quantiles <- quantile(data[[var]], seq(0, 1, 0.1))
  quantiles2 <- sapply(quantiles, function(x) breaks[which.min(abs(x - breaks))])

  data$bar <- as.numeric(as.character(
    cut(data[[var]], breaks, na.omit((breaks + dplyr::lag(breaks)) / 2)))
  )
  data$fill <- cut(data[[var]], quantiles2, na.omit((quantiles2 + dplyr::lag(quantiles2)) / 2))

  ggplot2::ggplot(data, ggplot2::aes(bar, y = 1, fill = fill)) +
    ggplot2::geom_col(position = 'stack', col = 1, show.legend = FALSE, width = diff(breaks)[1], size = 0.3) +
    ggplot2::scale_fill_brewer(type = 'qual', palette = 3) +
    ggplot2::theme_classic() +
    ggplot2::coord_fixed(diff(breaks)[1], expand = FALSE) +
    ggplot2::labs(x = 'x', y = 'count')
}
```

Use as:

```
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(1000))
decile_histogram(d, 'x')
```

Comment: @Axeman, very detailed answer. Thanks. How to add the labels as shown in the OP question on the plots of your answer, any suggestions?

Comment: You can use the `quantiles` vector to add some labels or lines, or `quantiles2` if you want to have them line up with the bars but be less exact. To have them at the correct height would require a bit more work. I did not bother since OP said he they were less important.

Comment: Something like `+ geom_vline(xintercept = quantiles[-11], lty = 2) +
  annotate('text', x = quantiles, y = Inf, label = names(quantiles), vjust = 1, hjust = 0)` could be useful.

Comment: @Axeman many thanks for your response. Although, I have not quite understood how to implement it in your given answer for the OP question, but I will figure it out. Cheers.